# What is the restoring force that brings the Blue Origin capsule back from flipping (at first)?

Tags: blue-origin, stability

In the early part of the recent Blue Origin video [Replay of Mission 9 Webcast](https://youtu.be/NRDhdHRyyjc)  they show footage of an earlier test of the capsule's emergency escape solid rocket from October 2016. Currently seen between `15:08` and `15:16` (between `T-08:50` and `T-08:42`) the capsule rocks (pitches?) back and forth by perhaps 90 degrees each way, before then appearing to flip over once.

For the rocking part, is there a restoring force from thrusters or other means, or is it just aerodynamic stability that brings it back at least until it completely flips?

Comment: the same video discussed the reaction control thrusters at the base of the capsule

Comment: @JCRM does it also exclude passive aerodynamic restoring forces?

Comment: I want to say its the aerodynamics of it and the fact the heavy parts are likely kept at the bottom (heat shield and thruster).